# Error testing guice dependeing injection

Tags: java, junit, inversion-of-control, guice

I was following this tutorial  [Why should we use dependency injection?](http://www.javacreed.com/why-should-we-use-dependency-injection/) and i have this class diagram
[image: Class Diagram]

and i have the following JUnit code to test model.

```
public class TestPerson {
    private Injector injector;
    @Before
    public void init(){
        injector = Guice.createInjector(new AbstractModule(){
            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                bind(MessageService.class).to(MockService.class);
            }
        });
    }
    @Test
    public void tetGreetFriend(){
        Person person = injector.getInstance(Person.class);
        person.gretFriends();
        MockService mockService = injector.getInstance(MockService.class);
        assertEquals("Hello my Friend", mockService.msg);
    }
}
```

when i start the test i get the following error

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<hello world> but was:<null>
```

what would be the problem of my code. I am new to IoC and DI

Comment: Please share the code for the related Classes and not the diagram

Comment: Also the error statement contradicts your code, in terms of `expected<>` in `Assert`

Answer (score 1):

The reason that the unit test is failing is because its intention is to test the side-effect on a `MockService` from calling `greetFriend()` but the side-effect occurs on a different instance of `MockService` from the one in the test:

```
@Test
public void tetGreetFriend(){
    Person person = injector.getInstance(Person.class);
    //one instance of MockService is being ^^ instantiated for injection into Person

    person.greetFriend();
    MockService mockService = injector.getInstance(MockService.class);
    //a distinct instance of MockService ^^

    assertEquals("Hello my Friend", mockService.message);
    }
}
```

To prevent this from happening, you can use the `@Singleton` annotation. This will mean that a Guice injector will not inject more than one instance of this dependency:

```
@Singleton
public class MockMessageService implements MessageService {

  public String subject;
  public String message;

  @Override
  public void sendMessage(String subject, String message) {
    this.subject = subject;
    this.message = message;
  }
}
```

The test will now pass.

Comment: I'm not sure what will satisfy you then - I copy and pasted your code, made that small modification, and it ran and passed on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know guice, only spring DI. But you might have forgotten the @inject

```
@Inject
public Person(MessageService messageService){
    this.messageService = messageService;
}
```

in your Person class?
And how ybout your MockService? In the tutorial they use

```
public class EmailService implements MessageService {
    @Override
    public void sendMessage(String subject, String message){
        System.out.printf("Email: %s, %s%n", subject, message);
    }
}
```

You should post the complete code, makes it easier to find problems.

Comment: I have thr prober annotation and code is a copy of what is in the tutorial :) thats why i have posted the link

Comment: @test11 even if you copy some code, you might have done a single error while copying that makes the error happen. So that's why we need you to copy your actual code.